# Append dictionary keys to an array instead of their values?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Currently writing a function that finds coordinates within a csv file that are within an area. I did managed to filtered the correct amount of coordinates that fits the conditions. However appending dictionary.keys into a blank array doesn't work..

```
def myFunction(File,Search_ID,d1,d2):
data = dict()
file = open(File)
first_line = True
for line in file:
    if first_line:
        first_line = False
    else:
        line = line.strip('\n').lower()
        (key, x, y, cat) = line.split(",")
        data[key] = x,y,cat

leng = len(d)

values = []

query = data.get(Search_ID.lower())
values.append([float(query[0]),float(query[1])])
rect_x = float(values[0][0])
rect_y = float(values[0][1])
values.append([rect_x+d1,rect_x-d1,rect_y+d2,rect_y-d2])

within_r = []
same_c = []


for i in data:
    lat = float(data[i][0])
    long = float(data[i][1])
    c = data[i][2]
    
    if lat < values[1][0] and lat > values[1][1]:
        if long < values[1][2] and long > values[1][3]:
            #Only get values instead of corresponding keys...
            within_r.append(data[i])

print(within_r)
```

The csv file is something similar to:

```
Identity,x,y,category
I01,5.2,3.6,M
I02,3.1,4.5,F
```

The `within_r.append(data[i])`can only get "Identity"'s values such as `[('5.2', '3.6', 'M'), ('3.1', '4.5', 'F')]` instead of Identity names.
If trying to do `data[i].keys()` will get error as `'tuple' object has no attribute 'keys'`. Not sure what is the way to make it only append keys instead of values.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do but isn't `i` the `key` you want?

Comment: This line looks wrong `data[key] = x,y,cat` shouldnt the x,y,cat be packed ?

Comment: @user655941 `x, y, cat` is a `tuple`..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are looking for, but if you need to append only the keys of the dictionary. You could simply do

```
within_r.append(i)
```

the variable "i" stores the key in it.